# How to create a ranking index based on row values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a ranking row index as the example below, based on the average on the last three months and the client ID column, the ranking index needs to be unique to each client:

```
Ranking Index   Client ID   Month 3 Month 2 Month 1 Avg
1                Client 2     6     5         3      4,66
1                Client 1      4    6         2      4
2                Client 1      5    2         1      2,66
2                Client 2      1    5         2      2,66
3                Client 2      4    2         1      2,33
3                Client 1      1    3         2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

you need `groupby` the column client ID and [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank) the column Avg, using the parameter `ascending=False` according to your expected output.

with a data example, you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clientID':list('baabba'), 'Avg':[4.66,4,2.66,2.66,2.33,2]})

# create the column ranking
df['ranking'] = df.groupby('clientID')['Avg'].rank(ascending=False)

print(df)
  clientID   Avg  ranking
0        b  4.66      1.0
1        a  4.00      1.0
2        a  2.66      2.0
3        b  2.66      2.0
4        b  2.33      3.0
5        a  2.00      3.0
```